# JQL - Get all issue based on project from result jql request

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jql

I need to get all project issue from dynamic jql issue.

Ex: project in (issue updated -5m)

It's there a way to do that in JQL ?

Comment: not clear what you really need to do..

Comment: The real concern, is to get all the task that are in a project, base on jql result. I mean, if i update a issue, i need to get all the open issue in the project of the updated issues

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from your additional clarification that you want a list of all outstanding tickets from any projects in which an issue has just been updated, then you can't do it via JQL in JIRA's issue search, but you could use the API. An example using jira-python library in Python 2.7:

```py
just_updated = jira.search_issues('updated >= -5m')
for issue in just_updated:
   issues = jira.search_issues('project = "' + issue.fields.project.key + '" and status not in (Resolved, Closed)')
   for each in issues:
      print each
```

This spits out the issue keys you want, which you can then turn into an HTML page with issue links or a CSV with issue details or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you're getting your results via an HTTP GET:

http://yourserver.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=YOUR_PROJ%20AND%20updated%20>%3D%20-5m

Replace "YOUR_PROJ" with your project's short name (key).